# Daily Google Sheets trigger csv import from CRM

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that I'm wanting to overwrite data on every day with a HTML link download that will also require a login and password to access.  Is there a way to use Google Sheets scripts to accomplish this?  For Example.  I'd like to import and overwrite starting with cell A1 with the first csv file, BA2 with the 2nd csv file, and DA2 with the third csv file.

For the last year I've had to manually download, and manually import these files each day for our reports to show up correctly.

Comment: Is your CRM system able to schedule report to your EMAIL?  If so, I have a solution for that. Otherwise, you have to code in the UrlfetchApp to get the report/data from your CRM. It can be complicated.

Comment: No it does not have the capability to email the downloads

Comment: Does it have API for accessing ? You might need to check in this way.